# Avaya switch - need to block port 25

Tags: smtp, port, block, avaya

Situation:

In QA-DEV Lab environment I need to block port 25 for the egress traffic on AVAYA ERS5510-48T switch.

Question:

How do I do it using EDM aka Web Interface? Couldn't find anything in Avaya's KB but believe it should be somewhere under QOS.

[Avaya web management screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXqf0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You'll do it via qos ACLs. I'd skip the web interface and do it on via CLI.
See chapter 7.1 of the following:

https://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/100123718

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance on best practices, Mark. Extremely valuable.